# CUDA: unspecified launch failure if used inside CU_SAFE_CALL

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA.

The following call

```
CU_SAFE_CALL(cudaGetLastError()) (infact any call inside CU_SAFE_CALL(...))
```

is giving an *'unspecified launch failure'* error.

And if I remove `CU_SAFE_CALL` and just run `cudaGetLastError()` it is running fine.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of CU_SAFE_CALL macro is to give you an error when there is an error in one of your CUDA calls... by removing it you will just make your program ignore the error that happened.
You need to figure out where the error is happening and fix it.
'unspecified launch failure' indicates a problem with the kernel launch.

Comment: BTW .. what do you mean by kernel launch ? Can you please explain.

Comment: @user2349144 by that i mean the kernel invocation. I hope you know what that means, if not, you really need to read the documentation. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#kernels

Comment: I don't know. I am really new to it. I will read the documentation. Thanks for the help.